# await Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#, asynchronous, console, async-await

I am currently building an asynchronous console application in which I have created classes to handle separate areas of the application.

I have created an InputHandler class which I envisioned would await Console.ReadLine() input. However, you cannot await such a function (since it is not async), my current solution is to simply:

```
private async Task<string> GetInputAsync() {
    return Task.Run(() => Console.ReadLine())
}
```

which runs perfectly fine. However, my (limited) understanding is that calling Task.Run will fire off a new (parallel?) thread. This defeats the purpose of async methods since that new thread is now being blocked until Readline() returns right?

I know that threads are an expensive resource so I feel really wasteful and hacky doing this. I also tried Console.In.ReadLineAsync() but it is apparently buggy? (It seems to hang).

Comment: Hmm, no, it does not defeat the purpose of async methods.  Which is to not block the caller.  Which certainly requires a thread, Console.ReadLine() is a blocking call.

Comment: Threads aren't necessarily an expensive resource as long as you don't go too far, or rather at times they are required in some fashion. If your console app is processing something in the background while waiting for Console.ReadLine() then it is a good idea.

Comment: Wouldn't that be `return await Task.Run( ( ) => Console.ReadLine( ) );`? I tried the way you wrote, but got a compiler error...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I know that threads are an expensive resource so I feel really wasteful and hacky doing this. I also tried Console.In.ReadLineAsync() but it is apparently buggy? (It seems to hang).

The console streams unfortunately do have surprising behavior. The underlying reason is that they *block* to ensure thread safety for the console streams. Personally I think that blocking in an asynchronous method is a poor design choice, but Microsoft decided to do this (only for console streams) and [have stuck by their decision](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779079/console-readlineasync-is-actually-blocking-when-it-should-be-returning-a-task-immediately).

So, this API design *forces* you to use background threads (e.g., `Task.Run`) if you do want to read truly asynchronously. This is not a pattern you should normally use, but in this case (console streams) it is an acceptable hack to work around their API.

> However, my (limited) understanding is that calling Task.Run will fire off a new (parallel?) thread.

Not quite. `Task.Run` will queue some work to the thread pool, which will have one of its threads execute the code. The thread pool manages the creation of threads as necessary, and you usually don't have to worry about it. So, `Task.Run` is not as wasteful as actually creating a new thread every time.

Comment: That Microsoft link is dead.  I'd fix it myself, but I couldn't find a replacement.

Comment: Yeah, they deleted all their bug reports a while ago. That's one way to get to zero bugs, I guess...